# Finding the velocity with parametric equations for the position of an object

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that an object in motion has the parametric equations $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.
Show that the speed of the object can be expressed as $$v(t) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac {dy}{dt} \right)^2} $$

Comment: A hint: Consider the parametric equations for x and y to be components of a position vector in 2D.  Their derivatives then could be considered to be components of a velocity vector.  Do you know how to calculate the magnitude of a vector?

Comment: This is the speed, not velocity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the object position is described by $p(t) = (x(t),y(t))$, then the object velocity is given by $\frac{d p(t)}{d t}  = (\frac{d x(t)}{d t} , \frac{d y(t)}{d t} )$, and hence the speed (not velocity!) is given by $\| \frac{d p(t)}{d t} \| = \sqrt{(\frac{d x(t)}{d t})^2 + (\frac{d y(t)}{d t})^2}$.

Comment: This is correct. It should be noted for OP's sake that speed is defined as only the magnitude of velocity. Velocity has direction, speed does not.