# Speed of a particle given parametric equations of x and y.

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

So my $x(t)=\pi t +\cos(2\pi t -(\pi/2))$, and my $y(t)=\pi t +\sin(2\pi t -(\pi/2))$.
I implicitly derived and got $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{(\pi+\cos(2\pi t -(\pi/2))*2\pi)}{(\pi-\sin(2\pi t -(\pi/2))*2\pi)}$$

From here, how do I find the tangent line when t=0 and also the speed when t=0?
Also, how do I determine the total amount of time the object has a non-negative vertical velocity during the time interval $0\le t \le1$  ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of problem, it's probably not a good idea to calculate $dy/dx$ and try to write the tangent line in the form $y=f(x)$. The problem is that curves described by these sorts of parametric equations will often have a vertical tangent somewhere, and this will cause problems.

A better approach is to write the tangent line in the form
$$
(y-y_0)\frac{dx}{dt} = (x-x_0)\frac{dy}{dt}
$$

This form doesn't suffer from any problems with vertical tangents.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Tangent line is $y-y_0=\dfrac{dy}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)^{-1}(x-x_0)$. Also, speed is simply $\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac {dy}{dt} \right)^2} $. For a derivation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495067/finding-the-velocity-with-parametric-equations-for-the-position-of-an-object). Vertical velocity is when $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ is $\geq0$.

Comment: Non-negative vertical velocity means that $dy/dt \ge 0$.

Comment: @bubba My mistake. Sorry. See my edit,